# Access page function from content-script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hello I'm making a chrome addon which automatically refreshes an element in the page using ajax, inside this element there's many thumbs up/down button (two of them per comment), the problem is that when I refresh the element these buttons doesn't work anymore, I used to fix it in greasemonkey by appending the required javascript file again after refreshing the element and then using jquery's click() to fix it, the code below worked fine with greasemonkey:

**greasemonkey script**

```
[.....rest of code mainly image swaps and basic stuff which works nicely.....]
[...element refreshed...]
//REMAP
$('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://url.com/pageScript.js"/>').appendTo($('head'));

    //THUMBS UP
    $(".ico-thumbs-up").click(function() {
        unsafeWindow.voting(this, "up", 6);
        return false;
    });
    //THUMBS DOWN
    $(".ico-thumbs-down").click(function() {
        unsafeWindow.voting(this, "down", 7);
        return false;
    });
unsafeWindow.checkVotedPosts();
[.....rest of code mainly image swaps and basic stuff which works nicely.....]
```

**contentScript.js**

```
[.....rest of code mainly image swaps and basic stuff which works nicely.....]
[...element refreshed...]
//REMAP
$('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + chrome.extension.getURL('inject/pageScript.js') + '"/>').appendTo($('head'));

    //THUMBS UP
    $(".ico-thumbs-up").click(function() {
        voting(this, "up", 6);
        return false;
    });
    //THUMBS DOWN
    $(".ico-thumbs-down").click(function() {
        voting(this, "down", 7);
        return false;
    });
checkVotedPosts();
[.....rest of code mainly image swaps and basic stuff which works nicely.....]
```

**pageScript.js**

```
*voting(); function*

*checkVotedPosts(); function*
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
      "matches": ["*://url.com/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "css": ["jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css", "inject/css.css"],
      "js": ["jquery/ajax_jquery_1.7.1.min.js", "contentScript.js"]
}
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "inject/pageScript.js"
  ],
```

Now that I'm using basically the same script but inside a chrome extension unsafeWindow doesn't work anymore, I searched and found a couple posts here in stackoverflow about injecting javascript in the page, I tried injecting a function which would call voting() in the page and then calling **that** function inside my script but didn't really succeded.

*(Also I'm waiting for DOMContentLoaded before doing all that)*

I'm new to coding in general so I'm sorry if it's something really simple and I'm wasting your time.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Hizan!